# read csv files into a list of data frames r

Tags: r

I tried looking for the answer to this but I could only find how to create individual data frames from csv files. I have many csv files in my working directory, and instead of assigning them to individual data frames by

```
frame1 = read.csv(filepath)
```

I would like have them contained in a list of data frames that I could do operations on. This would obviously require a loop over the files in dir(), but I am not sure of the syntax. In java I would do List.add() for each element.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like the following might be helpful.

```
my.path <- list("filepath1", "filepath2", "filepath3")
my.data <- list()
for (i in 1:length(my.path)){
    my.data[[i]] <- read.csv(my.path[[i]])
}
```

`my.data` is a list containing data frames

EDIT

The previous answer shows how to dynamically assign elements of a list. However, a more compact way to achieve your task would be

```
my.path <- list("filepath1", "filepath2", "filepath3")
my.data <- lapply(my.path, read.csv)
```

Comment: ah thanks for the answer, but i get number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Ok, so please provide a reproducible example that could be used to provide a solution.

Comment: i tried the compact way before I saw your edit. Thats the way I did it. Thank you

Comment: @Quantlbex I try this but now all the data files merge into one big frame, how do I separate or name them?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without listing the file paths, say, if they were all in one folder that isn't a working directory?

Comment: @jvalenti I guess you could simply do `my.path <- as.list(list.files("folderpath"))`.

Comment: Awesome: `my.data <- lapply(my.path, read.csv)`