# R: Apply mutate() to multiple data frames contained in a list, using each data frame's name as argument

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of named data frames that I read in the following way:

```
dfs <- list.files(pattern = "^[0-9]") |> lapply(read.csv)

names(dfs) <- list.files(pattern = "^[0-9]") |> {\(x) gsub(".csv", "", x)}() |> {\(x) gsub("-", ".", x)}()
```

Avoiding loops, I want to create a new column called "goal" in each data frame, and have it filled with the specific data frame's name.

I was planning to use `dplyr::mutate()`, however my many attempts were frustrated by failure - most of the times with:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
> no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class --something--

What I'd like to achieve is a vectorised version of:

```
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
  
  dfs[[i]] <- dfs[[i]] |> mutate(goal = names(dfs)[i])
}
```

Comment: With base R you would to `dfs <- Map(function(d, g) mutate(d, goal=g), dfs, names(dfs)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities using `purrr` and `dplyr`:

```r
dfs %>%
  imap(~ mutate(.x, goal = .y))

dfs %>% 
  map2(names(dfs), 
       ~ mutate(.x, goal = .y))
```

and one base `R` way:

```r
lapply(seq_along(dfs), function(n) transform(dfs[[n]], goal = names(dfs)[n]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep it completely in base R, you can use `Map` with `cbind`.

```
dfs <- Map(cbind, dfs, goal = names(dfs))
```